# WPF Nested Custom Markup Extension Bug Workaround in VS 2015 / 2017

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, markup-extensions

Am I doing something wrong or is this the [same bug that was reported in 2008](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/04/nested-markup-extension-bug)?

In the XAML snippet below I am using a custom markup extension:

```
<Image Source="{wpfx:IconEx Fill={StaticResource mybrush},
       Icon={StaticResource myicongeometry}}" />
```

`wpfx` is a prefix for my CLR Namespace that I imported in XAML.
`IconEx` is my custom public Markup Extension class that derives from `MarkupExtension`.

The image element is rendered correctly in the designer (that is the markup extension does its job), however when I try to build it in either VS 2015 or VS 2017 RC, I get this:

> Error: Unknown property 'Fill' for type 'MS.Internal.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser+UnknownMarkupExtension' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension.

Note that the property `Fill` is public on my markup extension class, as is the class itself. If I change the values of both `Fill` and `Icon` properties to not use `{ }` nested markup extension syntax, everything works. The problem is though that I cannot do that.

So, given that it's almost 2017 now, are there any workarounds that *do not use* the nested property syntax, as it looks like an overkill? Or did I do something wrong, and it;'s not a bug? Maybe I miss some attributes on my markup extension class or it's properties.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to use a `Path` control and set its `Fill` and `Data` properties?

Comment: @Clemens No, as far as I understand. First of all, this is a simplified example, the actual markup extension will have many more properties. And secondly it will be used many times in the xaml and not necessarily in an `Image` control.